# Firebase cloud function server side global variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It's possible to have a sort of a **global variable** on firebase cloud functions?

I mean I could have an **index.js** like that in which set-up a global variable, let's say `panicModeVariable`.

And I would like to check in my cloud functions this variable before doing anything, like here in the auth create user trigger.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var globalVariable = false;

// Create Account User
exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    if (!globalVariable) {
        const uid = event.data.uid
        const email = event.data.email
        const photoUrl = event.data.photoURL
    }
    [...]
```

I tried with two dummy functions

```
exports.setGlobal = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    globalVariable = true;
    response.send("Set " + globalVariable);
});

exports.getGlobal = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Read " + globalVariable);
});
```

But it seems that I cannot access this variable in the way I intended.

The writing function it uses a 'local' variable, while the reading one uses the initial value, always.

I'd like to do that, if it is possible, to have a sort of server side variable **to be read directly without the need to a call to the SDK to read, let's say, a database stored value** (so that to not have a function call counting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Environment Config variables https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

As far as I'm aware, you can't set them in the function themselves, they need to be set by CLI before you upload a function.

You could do something like `firebase functions:config:set panic.mode=true`

Then in your `createUserAccount` function you could call `functions.config().panic.mode`

But this won't help you `set` the variable via the `https` trigger. For that you'll need to make use of the database.