# Cloud Functions: Store Simple Shared Value Across Instances without Database/VPC?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Writing a firebase/google cloud function, and need to store an environment value for use across multiple function calls. That value expires and needs to be re-fetched on occasion and updated in production.

I'm looking for a *lightweight* option for that.  Seems all the advice I can find is that you need to spin up a VPC and create a dedicated Redis instance... or you need to create a cloud database and store it there... I just need to save a simple string, and it seems like an awful lot of infrastructure to do that.

One would think environment variables would work, but you can only set on the command line and they are only refreshed on deploy...

> To store environment data, you can use the firebase
>   functions:config:set command.
>
> To get environment data, you can use the functions.config() function.
>
> See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env.

So, is there a way to update/set a value in my code? I cannot rely on the command line to update it as it expires, like a cron to update and redeploy.

In Google Apps Script, for example, I'd just use the 'cache' helper service and store the value for a few hours. Any equivalent cache available to cloud functions without resorting to storing on GCS or in a database (it's a single, simple token string...)? Thanks.

Comment: What about creating a file (object) in Google Cloud Store (GCS) that is read at runtime by your cloud function?  It could be read on each function invocation.  You would have no infrastructure to maintain and changes to the value would be no more complex than setting a new file value.  Downside is the read cost of the object but I believe that to be very small.

Comment: I agree with both John Hanley and Kolban. You might look at related posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687786/firebase-functions-support-global-variable-across-functions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874686/firebase-cloud-function-server-side-global-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not offer any form of shared environment variables between functions. You will need to look to an external source such as Cloud Secrets Manager, Cloud Storage or one of the databases. I use both Cloud Storage and Datastore for this feature. I am now looking into Cloud Secrets Manager as my software usually has secrets as well.

Comment: Thank you for this. I couldn't even find Cloud Secret Manager in the array of services. This is exactly what I was looking for, as they can be updated via simple API call.